# Why is a old comment reply comment appearing at end of comment list as well

Tags: comments, ajax

EDIT:
Updated function to use get_comments offset param. Issue is still occurring.

I am displaying 5 comments at the end of an article and using ajax to request the rest of the comments.
On this page, 
http://www.universityaffairs.ca/opinion/in-my-opinion/phd-studies-in-canada-a-dilemma-for-international-students/#comments

the comment by Joshan Rodrigues is a reply to another comment. This is fine.

When I load the rest of the comments through ajax by clicking the More Comments link, Joshan Rodrigues' comment appears again at the end of the list, even if the comment date is older. Give it a try.

Below is function called by ajax.

```
function get_more_comments() {
global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

$comments = get_comments( 
                array(
                    'post_id'   => $_REQUEST['post_id'],
                    'status'    => 'approve',
                    'order'     => 'ASC',
                    'offset'    => 5,
                    'number'    => 1000
                )
            );

echo '<ol class="commentlist">';
wp_list_comments( 
            array(
                'avatar_size' => 0,
                'walker'    => new Walker_Comment_custom(),
            ),
            $comments
        );
echo '</ol>';

die(); 
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You are getting all comments by date ascending order, storing them in an array and stripping out the first 5 from that array. The comment of the issue is not in the first 5.

Comment: You got me on the right track, but the comment is not necessarily #6 so it is still appearing currently even if I slice off 7 elements off the array. I should be able to remove all comments and sub-comments from the list generated by ajax.

Comment: I said 6 at first time but I edited the comment quickly, not sure if you saw the comment before. If you read again I don't say that the comment is the number 6, I just said it is not in the first 5. In fact, it is the last one in date ascending order.

Comment: The issue is that the offset parameter applies only you the most recent comments. Since I was ordering comments in ascending, I wanted the 5 oldest comments to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a good way to get what you are trying to do is to use `comment__not_in` argument of `get_comments()` function. Send the IDs of the comments currently being displayed in the Ajax request and use them in the `comment__not_in` argument. For example, you could send those IDs as `comment__not_in[]` query var (array format):

```
$comment_not_in = $_REQUEST['comment__not_in'];
$comments = get_comments( 
                array(
                    'post_id'         => $_REQUEST['post_id'],
                    'status'          => 'approve',
                    'order'           => 'ASC',
                    'comment__not_in' =>  $comment_not_in,
                    'number'          => 1000
                )
            );
```

Also, I recommend to sanitize the data. As IDs are expected to be integer numbers we can do something like this:

```
$comment_not_in = array_map( 'intval', $_REQUEST['comment__not_in'] );
$comments = get_comments( 
                array(
                    'post_id'         => (int) $_REQUEST['post_id'],
                    'status'          => 'approve',
                    'order'           => 'ASC',
                    'comment__not_in' =>  $comment_not_in,
                    'number'          => 1000
                )
            );
```